# FacebookLikeView crashing all the time iOS

Tags: exception, ios5, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I've been using the FacebookLikeView classes in a lot of apps to enable Facebook profile liking within apps. Recently the code has started crashing in every app I've put it in. The Facebook app is setup correctly and everything. This is the line it is giving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on:

```
 else if ([fbEvent isEqualToString:@"xfbml.render"] && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(facebookLikeViewDidRender:)])
        [_delegate facebookLikeViewDidRender:self];
```

And it's being implemented like so:

```
_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:fbAppID andDelegate:self];
self.facebookLikeView = [[FacebookLikeView alloc]init];
[self.facebookLikeView setFrame:CGRectMake(117, 140, 82, 19)];
self.facebookLikeView.delegate = self;

self.facebookLikeView.href = [NSURL URLWithString:user];
self.facebookLikeView.layout = @"button_count";
self.facebookLikeView.showFaces = NO;
[self.facebookLikeView load];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your facebookLikeView to nil in your dealloc method or viewdidunload method